# Using Java's built-in Set classes to count unique values from a list

Tags: java, list, set

Given a list that could contain duplicates (like the one below), I need to be able to count the number of unique elements.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("M1");list.add("M1");
list.add("M2");list.add("M2");
list.add("M3");list.add("M3");
```

I think it can be done through the use of Java's Set.  How do I copy the list items into a set, and how do I get the count from the set?

Comment: Post some code with you trying to solve the problem, and the specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: Don't forget the parenthesis and semicolon on your list constructor.

Comment: I love how the question this is a so-called duplicate of was asked AFTER this one was... and by the same person.  Wouldn't it just have been easier to edit this question? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly.  It sounds like you're trying to use java's `Set` classes to count the number of unique entries in an ArrayList.  If this is so, you need to:

- Make a Set (you have to use a concrete class, I will use HashSet in the example)
- Iterate through the ArrayList, and put those items (Strings, in this case) into the set.  (I will use the addAll method)
- Get the Set's size

Example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
list.add("M1");
list.add("M1");
list.add("M2");
list.add("M3");

set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set.size());
```

EDIT: This solution is (for practical purposes) identical to Alexey's solution.  Alexey just posted while I was writing the solution.

Comment: I marked as correct answer, but in fact somebody have changed the name of the topic and content.

Answer (score 3):

```
...
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("M1");list.add("M1");
        list.add("M2");list.add("M2");
        list.add("M3");list.add("M3");

        HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();
        hashSet.addAll(list);
        System.out.println(hashSet.size()); 
...
```

it gives -

```
3
```